# How to find basis for this set?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

let $A$ be a $5 \times 7$ matrix

and let
$$K_A  = \left\{ X \in \mathbb{R}^7 | AX = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]^T \right\}$$

If I am given the matrix $A$, how do I find the basis for $K_A$?

Comment: $K_A$ is the nullspace of $A$, for which one can find a basis by considering the reduced row echelon form (rref) of the matrix.

Answer (score -1):

1. Find an orthonormal basis $b_1, \dots, b_k$ of $K_A^\perp$. To do this, notice that the rows of $A$ span $K_A^\perp$. Thus, we can apply Gram-schmidt process to them to get such a basis.
2. Extend $b_1, \dots, b_k$ to a basis $b_1, \dots, b_k, c_1, \dots, c_r$ of $\mathbb{R}^7$, for example by appending random vectors $c_1, \dots, c_r$ sampled from the standard Gaussian distribution.
3. Apply Gram-Schmidt process to the basis $b_1, \dots, b_k, c_1, \dots, c_r$. In the resulting list of vectors, the last $r$ vectors will constitute an orthonormal basis of $K_A$.

Comment: Since the question does not require an orthonormal basis, this approach seems overly complicated. Even if we were looking for an orthonormal basis, it would be easier to apply the Gram-Schmidt process with normalization to the basis constructed from the rref than to construct an orthonormal basis for the entire space $\mathbb{R}^7$.